# Passing JSON object and Javascript Variable through AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Im trying to pass a JSON object, and 2 javascript arrays in the same AJAX call.

I keep recieving this error

```
    System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: object
```

I believe this may be to do with the different types of variables being passed.

Any obvious errors you can spot?

Thanks

```
    var requestData = {
    "deptCode": userVar,
    "roundID": parseInt(roundIDVar),
    "moduleCode": moduleCodeVar,
    "priority": parseInt(priorityVar),
    "day": parseInt(dayVar),
    "start": parseInt(timeVar)-8,
    "length": parseInt(lengthVar),
    "weeks": weeksNum,
    "capacity": parseInt(studentsVar),
    "type": roomTypeVar,
    "otherReqs": otherReqs
};
var obj = JSON.stringify(requestData);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/create/Submit',
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Submitting Failed. Please Reload and Try Again.");
    },
    data: {JSONdata:obj,weeks:weeksVar,facilities:facilitiesValue },
    datatype: 'html',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    async:false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Controller

```
     public ActionResult Submit(request JSONdata, String[] Weeks, String[] facilities) {
        ViewBag.module = JSONdata.weeks;
        if(JSONdata.otherReqs==null){
            JSONdata.otherReqs = "None";
        }
        JSONdata.sent = 1;
        JSONdata.status = 0;
        JSONdata.viewed = 0;
        JSONdata.booked = 0;
        db.requests.Add(JSONdata);

        try
        {
            // Your code...
            // Could also be before try if you know the exception occurs in SaveChanges

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
        if(Convert.ToInt16(JSONdata.weeks)==1){
            for (var i = 0; i < Weeks.Length; i++) {
                weeks_request newWeek = new weeks_request();
                newWeek.week = Convert.ToInt16(Weeks[i]);
                newWeek.requestID = JSONdata.requestID;
                db.weeks_request.Add(newWeek);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Try to stringify the entire data you're sending: JSON.stringify({JSONdata:obj,weeks:weeksVar,facilities:facilitiesValue }),

Comment: @william.taylor.09 ok that worked as far as passing the data goes. How would i deal with this on the other end?

Comment: Deserialize it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx

Comment: @william.taylor.09 sorry to seem dim, but what data type would this deserialize to?

Comment: @william.taylor.09 not to worry, i created a model to hold the various data types. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user2976358 Now that you've done that, you can get rid of serializing the data at all and change your method to take your model in as a parameter. ASP.NET should automatically serialize it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with traditional: true in your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/create/Submit',
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert("Submitting Failed. Please Reload and Try Again.");
},
data: {JSONdata:obj,weeks:weeksVar,facilities:facilitiesValue },
datatype: 'html',
contentType: 'application/json',
processData: false,
async:false,
traditional: true,
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

});